# how do I schedule a task in Wordpress to run once a week

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

wp_schedule_event($timestamp, $recurrence, $hook, $args);

$recurrence
    (string) (required) How often the event should reoccur. Valid values are below. You can create custom intervals using the cron_schedules filter in wp_get_schedules().

```
    hourly
    twicedaily
    daily

    Default: None
```

But what if i want to run my task once a week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the manual: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_schedules

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_weekly' );

 function cron_add_weekly( $schedules ) {
    // Adds once weekly to the existing schedules.
    $schedules['weekly'] = array(
        'interval' => 604800,
        'display' => __( 'Once Weekly' )
    );
    return $schedules;
 }
```